# How dose recursion task in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

This code is a 4-bit input value for factorial, and the output result is 32 bits, this section it compiles without problems, but looking at the output VCD file I can't see the waveform I want, I carefully read it many times but I don't know what the problem is. Hope to be able to help.

```
module cal_4jiecheng(out,in);
    output [31:0] out;
    input [3:0] in;
    reg [31:0] out;
    initial
    begin
        cal_4_4 (out,in);
    end
task automatic cal_4_4;
    output [31:0] out2;
    input [3:0] in1;
    reg [31:0] out11;
    begin
        if (in1>=2) begin
            cal_4_4(out11,in1-1);
            out2=in1*out11;
        end
        else
            out2=1;
    end
endtask
endmodule
```

test_bench:

```
`timescale  1ns / 1ps
`include "test4.v"
module top;
reg [3:0] IN;
wire [31:0] OUT;
cal_4jiecheng cal4(OUT,IN);

initial
begin
    IN=2;
end
initial
begin
    $dumpfile("./test4.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,top);
    #10000 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: You need to tell us the output you are expecting and why?

Comment: Waveform shows progressing of values over time (expressed via clocks or value changes). There are no clocks in your design and no input value changes (except for initial one). So, there is no progress, your waive form will probably contain a single change only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the module cal_4jiecheng to generate the factorial of an integer on input port changes, you should add an always block, not an initial block. Try to re-write the module like the following:

```
module cal_4jiecheng(out,in);
    output [31:0] out;
    input [3:0] in;
    reg [31:0] out;
    always @*
    begin
        cal_4_4 (out,in);
    end
...
endmodule
```